# Disable Tab Control when pressing Button VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I would like to ask if how could possibly disable tabs in tabcontrol.

This is what the codes looks like when disable:

```
 Public Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
    If e.TabPageIndex = 3 Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

- This code only disable while you load the form
  I was trying to convert a code from c# however it doesn't work as I expected.

See this code:

```
Public Sub EnableTabs(ByVal Page As TabPage, ByVal bolFlag As Boolean)
    EnableControls(Page.Controls, bolFlag)
End Sub
Private Sub EnableControls(ByVal Ctrls As Control.ControlCollection, ByVal bolFlag As Boolean)
    For Each Ctrl As Control In Ctrls
        Ctrl.Enabled = bolFlag
        EnableControls(Ctrl.Controls, bolFlag)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'I have problems with this line
    EnableTabs(TabControl1.TabPages(TabControl1.SelectedIndex) = 0, False)
End Sub
```

Is there anyway that I could possibly disable a tab while clicking a button?

Let me know!

Thanks,

Regards,
Alvin

Comment: " doesn't work as I expected." means what?

Comment: TabControl1.TabPages(TabControl1.SelectedIndex) = 0 evaluates to a Boolean, not a TabPage.  So of course that cannot work.  Very hard to guess what the possible intention might have been.

Comment: Hi Hans, I just copied the code from c# and when I tried it. I'm expecting the same code structure as vb.net but it doesn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have already my own answer based on it.  And I used this code right now, for example I have 3 tabs with 0-2 index respectively.

```
Public Sub Tab0Flag As Boolean
Public Sub Tab1Flag As Boolean
Public Sub Tab2Flag As Boolean

Public Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
If e.TabPageIndex = 0 Then
    e.Cancel = Tab0Flag
End If
If e.TabPageIndex = 1 Then
    e.Cancel = Tab1Flag
End If
If e.TabPageIndex = 2 Then
    e.Cancel = Tab2Flag
End If
End Sub
Private Sub EnableTabs(ByVal Tab0 As Boolean, ByVal Tab1 As Boolean, ByVal Tab2 As Boolean)
Tab0Flag = Tab0
Tab1Flag = Tab1
Tab2Flag = Tab2
End Sub

Private Sub frmG_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'I'll Only Disable the 2nd tab
EnableTabs(False, True, False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
    Dim tabPage As TabPage

    For Each tabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
        If tabPage.Text ="TabPage1"
            tabPage.Enabled =False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Button1_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TabControl1.TabPages(0).Enabled =false
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I think we shared the same idea. Thanks, really appreciate that much.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer.

At some point if you want to disable a tab - use this code at the appropriate point

```
    TabControl1.TabPages(x).Enabled = False
```

Where x is the zero-based index of the tab page you want to disable.

When the user clicks on a TabPage, the `Selecting` event fires for the whole control. Using the `e` eventargs parameter you can see the index of the TabPage being selected. The code in this event checks to see if it is disabled and if so, cancels the tab click.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
    If e.TabPage.Enabled = False Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there! I have way right now on how to disable the tabs

Answer (score -1):

I already answered it.  Anyhow, I would like to share it for you guys.

I just change the code from:

```
EnableTabs(TabControl1.TabPages(TabControl1.SelectedIndex) = 0, False)
```

to:

```
EnableTabs(TabControl1.TabPages(1), False)
```

This code only the contain of tab not by disable while selecting/clicking the tab header.  I think I just use this one for now.  If you have other source of code that is useful enough.  Just leave on the answer section below.  I loved to hear them all.

Thanks anyway.

Regards, 
Alvin